# MongoDB : '-bash: mongo: command not found' after installation with Homebrew and NPM on Mac

Tags: mongodb, bash, command

Currently, I am trying to install MonogoDB on Mac.

I have installed with both HomeBrew and npm.
But still there are two problems,

**1) I can not use on the command line,**

*-bash: mongodb: command not found*

**2) still can't run MongoDB with below error by 'node mongodb-test.js'**

*Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)*

- [I followed this link for Homebrew](https://www.robinwieruch.de/mongodb-macos-setup/)

// Just want to try run it for test

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  dbo.createCollection("customers", function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Collection created!");
    db.close();
  });
});
```

- People said the MongoDB is loacated in /usr/local/var/mongodb if I used HomeBrew. However, when I check the folder, it's empty..

Do you guys think it didn't install properly somehow..

Comment: Are you able to connect to mongodb from terminal using `mongo` command.

Comment: The thing is I can't. That's odd to me. I installed with npm first and, tried with other options from the stack overflow. (ex. npm link mongodb) and I saw one guy said HomeBrew is easier to configure for MongoDB on Mac so I tried with HomeBrew as well but.. still it's like that :(

Comment: Check if you have any log files created in /data/db or /data folder.

Comment: @Mani Thanks, I reinstalled with HomeBrew then I was able to see the folders created by MongoDB. I am not quite sure what was the problem but it seems fixed. If any problems like this, feel free to leave comment here. Will do my best to support you guys since I spent several hours. :/